# Laravel - Salvar dados no banco apenas se não existir e.......

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, checkbox, sql-insert

Estou com um sistema de cadastro de pessoa e nele há uma área com diversos campos de checkbox que representam os grupo sociais que a atual pessoa representa:

**TABELAS**

**pessoa**

```
id | nome
1  | João
2  | Maria
3  | Ana
```

**grupo**

```
id | grupo
1  | Lorem1
2  | Lorem2
3  | Lorem3
```

**grupo_pessoa**

```
id | id_grupo | id_pessoa
1  |     1    |      1
2  |     1    |      2
3  |     2    |      1
```

E estou com o seguinte código no meu controller para salvar as alterações:

**PessoaController**

```
    $grupo = $request->grupo; //retornando valores dos campos checkbox

    for($x = 0; $x < count($grupo); $x++){
        array_push($query_grupo, array('id_grupo' => $grupo[$x], 'id_pessoa' => $id));      
    }
    DB::table('grupo_pessoa')->insert($query_grupo);
```

Eu preciso remover da tabela os grupos que eu desmarco e salvar os selecionados apenas se não existirem ainda.

Eu tentei usar o "save" pq dizem que ele já faz essa verificação mas não funcionou da forma que tentei:

```
$grupo_pessoa = new GrupoPessoa;

        for($x = 0; $x < count($grupo); $x++){
            $grupo_pessoa->id_grupo = $grupo[$x];
            $grupo_pessoa->id_pessoa = $id;
            $grupo_pessoa->save();

            array_push($query_grupo, array('id_grupo' => $grupo[$x], 'id_pessoa' => $id));

        }
```

Comment: vc conhece o sync ou o attach e dettach? Veja aqui que encontrará... https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships se não conseguir faço um modelo hoje mais tarde. Abs

Comment: Nunca usei e é bem complexo kkkk vou ver se entendo.

Comment: é tranquilo na verdade. sua tabela de ligação nem precisa de id, pode ter somente as duas chaves da tabela pessoa e grupo ambas como sendo chave primária e ficará inclusive mais rápida a pesquisa. Faça um teste simples primeiro e verá que é bem simples. Tenho algo pronto, mas não consegui achar aqui. Te mandarei um exemplo pronto depois. Abs

Comment: Legal a resposta do João é bem isso. Não consegui terminar... mas farei em breve pra ficar como referência, segue: https://github.com/code-sample/laravel-many-to-many Devo terminar hj a noite ou amanhã. Tenho de fazer as views... se quiser ajudar. Abs

Answer (score 1):

No relacionamento muitos para muitos, é identificado pela chave primária de outras duas tabelas, formando o conjunto que identifica a chave primária da tabela intermediária, ou seja, aquele que recebe as duas chaves.

Em seu caso eu observei que colocou um chave primária que identifica cada registro de sua tabela, e dois campos que são os que relacionam as chaves primárias. Será que é preciso (redundante) ???

Em Laravel, o [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) ORM faz o trabalho pesado, então se for configurado como especificado logo abaixo é um simples comando. Exemplificando:

**Tabela Pessoa** `(class pessoa)`

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pessoa extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'pessoa';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable   = ['nome'];
    public  $timestamps   = false;

    public function grupo()
    {           
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Grupo','grupo_pessoa','id_pessoa', 'id_grupo');
    }
}
```

---

**Tabela Grupo** `(class grupo)`

```
    <?php namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Grupo extends Model
    {
        protected $table      = 'grupo';
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        protected $fillable   = ['grupo'];
        public  $timestamps   = false;

        public function pessoa()
        {           
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pessoa','grupo_pessoa','id_grupo','id_pessoa');
        }
    }
```

---

A sua tabela `grupo_pessoa` nesse caso exemplo tem que ficar com dois campos somente: *(Layout)*

```
grupo_pessoa
id_grupo | id_pessoa
```

A relação [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) é nesse formato, eu tive que colocar os campos na configuração, porque o padrão seria o nome da `tabela`, `undescore` e `id` da *tabela*, no seu caso o `id` vem na frente, mas, na configuração colocada funciona da mesma forma **reescrevendo** a maneira do [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) saber o nome do campo que ***relaciona***.

A pergunta se resume agora nesse comando simples e fácil o [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships), aonde ele verifica ao enviar o array de informações quais informações tem na tabela ai ele não faz nada, quais não tem ele insere como novo registro e as que foram retiradas ele remove. Na verdade esse comando em um [detach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) e um [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) do [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) em sequencia.

```
$pessoa = App\Pessoa::findOrFail(1);
$pessoa->grupo()->sync([1,2,3];
```

Essa seria a forma correta, e ideal, seguindo a nomenclatura do próprio Framework de persistência o [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) no relacionamento simples de [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

***Leia:***

[Eloquent ManyToMany - Relacionamentos Muitos para Muitos](http://artesaos.github.io/howto/eloquent-many-to-may/)

[github - code-sample/laravel-many-to-many](https://github.com/code-sample/laravel-many-to-many)

Comment: Legal João bem isso mesmo. Vou fazer um modelo para futura referência. Vejo que isso é uma questão recorrente com o Laravel. Estou começando aqui: https://github.com/code-sample/laravel-many-to-many

Comment: Boa @Evert legal ... demais ... parabéns, vou colocar o seu link na resposta!